# MOSS Filter webpart not working with & symbol in the query string

Tags: c#, url, moss, urlencode, url-encoding

I know this is a fairly common error with URL encoding. The problem I suspect is the MOSS Filter webpart used to filter a dataview webparts results based on the querystring paramter passed to it from the Filter webpart.

When the query string contains an & (ampersand) symbol the dataview webpart is unable to display any results but **does not** display any errors.

When I replace the ampersand in the query string below with %26 then I get an exception 'Input string was not in a correct format'

http://localhost/subsite/Pages/Test.aspx?SS=Test%20Governance%20&%20Directors 
no error caused but filter (SS) passed to the Data view webpart shows no results.

http://localhost/subsite/Pages/Test.aspx?SS=Test%20Governance%20%26%20Directors 
replacing the & with %26 produces an exception 'Input string was not in a correct format' is thrown

Can we use the ampersand in the query string from a Filter webpart?  I have read that the consumer webpart reads this as another parameter being passed to it, maybe that is the problem? Though I have configured the Filter webpart to only pass the first parameter.

Comment: I know nothing of MOSS, but the second URL with %26 is absolutely the correct way to include an ampersand in a query parameter. If it chokes on it, I'd count that as a bug. There is some talk of double-URL-encoding this one character (`?SS=Test%20Governance%20%2526%20Directors`) — does that do anything for you?

Comment: thanks Bob, but double encoding didn't produce the filter results it also didn't cause an error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just had to change & to and in the end...

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in SP's Query String URL Filter web part.

The Query String URL Filter will not work if the field Type is "Multiple Lines of Text" and the value includes the '&' character.  Even if you encode it to %26.

Change the column type to "Single Line of Text".  See if that magically solves your problem.

Comment: what if the requirement makes op to use multiple text line,

Comment: Kumar, Good comment.  We have no control over what the client's requirements are.  If the field type must be "Multiple Lines of Text", then the & character must be replaced with something else in the list.  Another option if for MS to fix their Query String URL Filter web part bug so it properly supports fields that are of type "Multiple Lines of Text".

Answer (score 0):

For me in sharepoint 2010 sp1 august updates with the query string (URL) filter, bobince's double url encode worked for me..  Thanks bob i was pulling my hair out

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint will encode `&` to `%26` if not encoded then encode `&` to `%26`.
Also add the parameter `&useFiltersInViewXml=1` to the filter view URL. It should work for you.

Comment: I can't make out what the second "encode & to %26" is doing there.